# how to display absolute url of a websevice in play framework

Tags: web-services, playframework

I am new to play framework. I am having a web service url. To that url I am appending some parameters. I want display that url after appending the values to that url.
Here is my code:

```
public JsonNode getCustomerDetails(CustomerDto customerDto){
    String feedUrl = Constants.ERP_CUSTOMER_URL;
    WSRequestHolder wsHolder = null;
    wsHolder = WS.url(feedUrl);
    wsHolder.setAuth(Constants.ERPUSERNAME, Constants.ERPPASSWORD,Realm.AuthScheme.BASIC);
    whereClause.append("mobileno='").append(customerDto.getMobile()).append("'")
                .append(ORDER_BY_UPDATED_ASC);
    wsHolder.setQueryParameter(_WHERE, whereClause.toString());``
    F.Promise<WS.Response> response = wsHolder.get();
    json = response.get().asJson();
}
```

`Constants.ERP_CUSTOMER_URL` is my webservice url to that I am appending `mobileno`. I want to display the absolute url of my webservice after appending the values to it. I tried to display `wsHolder` but it is displaying as `play.libs.WS$WSRequestHolder@6afe06a7`

Answer (score 0):

You can see it with getUri() on the [WS.Response](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse) object like:

```
response.get().map((Function) response -> {
     System.out.println(response.getUri());      
   }
);
```